# Удаление с начала строки

Tags: delphi

Процедура, удаляет **с конца строки и до указанного по счету символа**: весь текст.

**Как сделать что бы процедура делал то же самое только с начала строки ?:**

```
procedure Del(var s: string);
var
  i, c,k: integer;
  m:string;
begin
  c := 0;
  m := frm_Main.Edit1.text;
  k := frm_Main.SpinEdit1.Value;
 for i := Length(s) downto 1 do
begin
    if s[i] = m then
      Inc(c);
    if c = k then
    begin
      Delete(s, i + 1, Length(s) - i);
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**Я переделал вот в таком виде, но не работает:**

```
procedure Del(var s: string);
    var
      i, c,k: integer;
      m:string;
    begin
      c := 0;
      m := frm_Main.Edit1.text;
      k := frm_Main.SpinEdit1.Value;
     for i := Length(s) downto 1 do
    begin
        if s[i] = m then
          Inc(c);
        if c = k then
        begin
          Delete(s, 1, i); // Вот тут внес изменения.....!
          break;
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

Пробую развернуть цикл: **for i := 1 to Length(s)** do и тоже не срабатывает. В чем же загвоздка ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут все очень просто, на самом деле: Денис, смотрите, Вы практически все правильно сделали, только не можете все склеить в единый код.

Ответ на ваш вопрос (точнее код который Вы хотели, используя procedure Del):

```
procedure Del(var s: string);
var
  i, c, k: integer;
  m: string;
begin
  c := 0;
  m := frm_Main.Edit1.text;
  k := frm_Main.SpinEdit1.Value;
  // А тут как и Вы написали, да, развернуть цикл в другом направлении.
  for i := 1 to Length(s) do
  begin
    if s[i] = m then
      Inc(c);
    if c = k then
    begin
      // В этом месте все правильно
      Delete(s, 1, i);
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```